# How to disabe FullAjax plugin for all the pages except one

Tags: joomla-2.5, development, extensions, joomla-api

I've installed FullAjax plugin and I need to disable it for all the pages except the page with some parameter something like:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'view=orders&layout=details') !== false) {
// enable plugin for this page
} else {
// disable plugin for all other pages
}
```

The options **Ignore menu items** and **Do not use FullAjax on** in plugin configurations don't suite because many pages don't have menu items but I need to disable the plugin on them too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pages I need to disable the plugin for are pages of single VM orders that are being generated every time when a shopper make an order so it's impossible to create menu items for these pages. At the same time I've already found the following solution:

to open **plugins/system/addfullajax/addfullajax.php**, find the condition that starts from the row 90:

```
if(get_class($doc) != 'JDocumentHTML'
```

and to comment this condition including the row:

```
} elseif($this->nedAjaxRespons) {
```

and below to write our new condition:

```
if($app->input->get('option') == 'com_virtuemart' && $app->input->get('view') == 'orders') {
```

and to comment the row 155:

```
//$this->axJsAllowed = true;
```

and copy-past this row before the end of our condition

Answer (score 0):

Then create fake menu item for page in question, and refer to it in plugin config. I always create fake menu called "Virtual menu" for similar menu items which are not to be shown in any menu on front-end, but help in many cases.